# Handle workspace/monorepo with different deployments

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am using yarn workspaces in which I have 3 projects.

```
My-project
   folder-1
   folder-2
   folder-3
```

Some devs work on folder-1, others on folder-2 and the rest on folder-3. The flow of the release is the following:

- PRs are created on feature branches and merged to develop.
- The process of PRs continue and they all get merged to develop. At some point, we decide whether release is due, so develop is merged into main branch.
- From main, we create a release candidate and deploy scripts on productions are run.

The problem that happens for us is that folder-3 project needs to be released much quicker(every day), whereas folder-1's release happens very rarely(every month) even though folder-1 changes every day(it's just release must happen every month).

**The problem:** When the team works on feature branches and merges things to develop, it happens that develop branch ends up containing folder-1 and folder-3's changed files. If we want to release folder-3 every day, we got no choice but to merge develop into main in which case changed folder-1’s code also moves into main which is not ideal, because folder-1’s release must happen every month, not every day.

One thing that I looked into is using `git checkout /paths` which only moves the specific folder from one branch to another - i.e I could use this to only move folder-1 from develop to main, but I am not sure if this is the right and best practice.

Comment: What is the relationship between folder-1, folder-2, and folder-3? Would it make sense to split the repo?

Comment: No, It won't make sense to split it. It wouldn't make much sense for me to explain what the contents of folders are. Assume that it can't be split.

Comment: 1) [If you withhold info about your problem, we can't help you find alternative solutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Fancy checkouts and complex merges are rarely a good solution. 2) Sometimes you say folder-1 releases every day and folder-1 every month, sometimes you say the opposite. Which is it? 3) "*...folder-3's code also moves into main which is not ideal, because folder-3's release must happen every month, not every day.*" This implies merging to main also causes a release? We need to know more about your release process.

Comment: 1) I don’t withhold anything, you said if the projects can be split and if that were possible, I would not even ask the question. 2) fixed/updated. Sorry 3)   We want ‘main’ to only contain the latest, currently released code. Even though folder-1’s code could change multiple times during a month, we dont want it released until the whole month expires, so the code of folder-1 should not end up on main until it is ready to be released.

Comment: When you merge develop into main, `git merge -n develop` which will perform the merge but not commit it. Then unstage anything you don't want to merge and commit. Again, fancy merge workflows usually just create more problems. I'd advise re-examining the assumption that the repo cannot be split.

Comment: You may want to consider scraping main and instead making a branch off develop for every release. This branch would have just one commit, a commit that removes the other folders.